# Retrieve cookie value with Gatling

Tags: scala, http, gatling

I'm kinda new to Gatling and I'd like to get the value from a cookie. I tried many ways to do so but I might misunderstand something.

At first I'm doing a post request to my auth API which create the cookie I want.

Then I've tried :

```scala
   .exec {
      session => println(session)
      println(session.attributes)

      // return a Some object whose value is of type CookieJar (with apparently private access)
      println(session.attributes.get("gatling.http.cookies"))

      /*
      // Doesn't compile due to CookieJar being private
      val value: CookieJar = session.attributes.get("gatling.http.cookies") match {
        case None => None
        case Some(cj: CookieJar) => cj
      }
      print(value)
      */

      // return a GetCookieBuilder which doesn't seem really useful
      println(getCookieValue(CookieKey("COOKIE_NAME")))

      session
    }
```

Do you have any idea about it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getCookieValue` is a DSL component, not a method you can call in your own functions.

It's used as a scenario step to extract a cookie value from the internal CookieJar and copy it in the Session as a dedicated attribute.

```scala
exec(getCookieValue(CookieKey("COOKIE_NAME")))
.exec { session =>
  println(session("COOKIE_NAME").as[String])
  session
}
```